# Reflection loading FAILURE in Sharepoint and SUCCESS in Console

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I'm facing a problem loading via refletion my class.

this code:

```
PublishingClass = Type.GetType("CONST STRING FULLY QUALIFIED", true);
```

Works if I'm in a console app but fails (Could not Load "CONST STRING FULLY QUALIFIED") if I'm in Sharepoint context.

Why some classes loads from the same DLL and other not?

Why from console app all class loads EVERY CLASS and from sharepoint no?

I'm running on my machine, copying to gac, resetting IIS and recycling AppPool..

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you include the full assembly information? Like for `string` it's: `System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089` I know for some platforms (not sure about sharepoint) you need _all_ of that information to resolve a type.

Comment: Can you provide the _actual_ string you're using instead of `"CONST STRING FULLY QUALIFIED"`?

Comment: Type.GetType("NTV.GI.InformationsPublishingModules.clPublish_NOE_InfoPanelAlto,NTV.GI.DefaultPublishingModules, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=058a5c6182ba3fb9")

Answer (score 0):

You already try with that?

```
Type.GetType("CONST STRING FULLY QUALIFIED, AssemblyName");
```

Comment: It's not `namespaceName`, that should be `AssemblyName`.

Comment: Type.GetType("NTV.GI.InformationsPublishingModules.clPublish_NOE_InfoPanelAlto,NTV.GI.DefaultPublishingModules, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=058a5c6182ba3fb9")